# Question on the proof of Cauchy Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is the proof for the general case given in wikipedia.

In the general case, let Z be the center of G, which is an abelian subgroup. If p divides |Z|, then Z contains an element of order p by the case of abelian groups, and this element works for G as well. So we may assume that p does not divide the order of Z; since it does divide |G|, the class equation shows that there is at least one conjugacy class of a non-central element a whose size is not divisible by p. But that size is $[G : C_G(a)]$, so p divides the order of the centralizer $C_G(a)$ of a in G, which is a proper subgroup because a is not central. This subgroup contains an element of order p by the inductive hypothesis, and we are done.

My question is why it says the size of the conjugacy class of a is not divisible by p but $[G : C_G(a)]$ is divisible by p? I thought the size is equal to $[G : C_G(a)]$? Is it not true that the index and size of a group are the same? If not, what is the difference.

Comment: It does not say that $[G:C_G(a)]$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: then what does it say? i don't quite understand

Comment: It says that the size of the conjugacy class is NOT divisible by $p$, and that the size of the conjugacy class is $[G:C_G(a)]$. It then concludes that the size of $C_G(a)$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: why it can conclude that the size of $C_G(a)$ divisible by p?

Answer (score 1):

$|G|=[G:C_G(a)][C_G(a)]$ . Since $p$ divides $|G|$ and it does not divide $[G:C_G(a)]$ so it divides $[C_G(a)]$ .It says this

Comment: i don't quite understand the difference between $[G:C_G(a)]$ and $[C_G(a)$. Can you kindly explain their difference

Comment: Note that $[C_G(a))]$ is not standard notation for the size of $C_G(a)$. Usually, one uses $|C_G(a)|$.

Comment: can i know where i can find the derivation of this formula?

Comment: @user136266 This is just a special case of Lagrange's index theorem.

Comment: lagrange formula is saying one is the number of cosets and one is the size of the group but here these two operands are both sizes, one is the size of conjugacy class and one is the size of centraliser. I can't link them together.

Comment: @user136266 Ahh, in that case, you are looking for the orbit-stabilizer theorem, which links the size of a conjugacy class with the index of the centralizer.